# date format gets changed when converting to string in ASP.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datetimepicker, datetime-format

```
$(function() {
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-dd-mm',
        onSelect: function(datetext){
            var d = new Date(); // for now

            var h = d.getHours();
            h = (h < 10) ? ("0" + h) : h ;

            var m = d.getMinutes();
            m = (m < 10) ? ("0" + m) : m ;

            var s = d.getSeconds();
            s = (s < 10) ? ("0" + s) : s ;

            datetext = datetext + " " + h + ":" + m + ":" + s;

            $('#datepicker').val(datetext);
        }
    });
});
```

I have used this jquery..
But on converting this to string in ASP, ASP is returning me in another format (say 1/9/2016 ... But the format what asp should return me as string is 01/09/2016). Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: How you pass your date into ASP.NET? Can you post server-side code?

Answer (score 2):

you can use
`String.Format("{0:yy-dd-mm}", yourParseTime);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Format()` in C#. Just pass your textbox date in `String.Format()`.

**Try this Code :**

```
using System;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now; 

    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:yy-dd-mm}", time));
}
}
```

**Demo :**[Click here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MajqvM)